# Reading an OBJ file with Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use the `wavefront-obj` package to read an OBJ file. Here is [an example of OBJ file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/master/assets/models/pinecone.obj).

After downloading this file, I do

```
import Data.WaveFrontObj
x <- loadWavefrontObj "pinecone.obj"
```

Then:

```
> :t x
x :: Either String WavefrontModel

import Data.Either.Extra
y = fromRight' x
```

Then:

```
> :t y
y :: WavefrontModel
> y
WavefrontModel []
```

Looks like the result is empty. What am I doing bad ?

Comment: The wavefront-obj repository hasn't been updated in 2 years, and the version is marked as 0.0.1 with an "experimental" tag. Looks like this was just a small parser someone got together on a weekend or so, it's not surprising it doesn't quite work for all inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your OBJ file has some directives that wavefront-obj doesn't recognize. You can see [in the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wavefront-obj-0.1.0.1/docs/src/Data-WavefrontObj-Parsers.html#loadWavefrontObj) that wavefront-obj only understands the `#`, `v`, `vt`, `vn`, and `f` directives. Your file kicks off with `mtllib` and `o` directives, and appears to have several others not in the supported list.

A priori, I would therefore expect a `Left` result instead of a `Right` as you're getting. But the wavefront-obj author fell into a common parser-combinator pitfall: their top-level parser does not end with `eof`. So it sees the first two comment lines, then none of its parsers match the next line but it doesn't mind not being at the end of the file, so it reports successfully parsing an empty list of directives.

Between this and a few other things I noticed while sourcediving (comments are almost certainly not treated correctly, failure to exploit the predictable structure of directives and therefore code duplication), I expect you're going to have to do quite a bit of work if you want this package to work reliably and correctly.

Comment: The `readOBJ` function of the `rgl` package for R ignores unknown directives. I expected the same. I think the best I can do is my own "readOBJ" function, without using this package.

Comment: Well, at least let me share the pinecone (done with R): [pinecone](https://media.giphy.com/media/zmksFMLFWIWg6ybt23/giphy.gif). I hope you appreciate ;)